# Jackson JSON - timestamps with ids

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jackson

I have Json where first value is String with id and next value is timestamp Integer:

```
{
    "1": 1490211618,
    "2": 1492964836,
    "3": 1478099371,
    "4": 1492752948,
    "5": 1478100215,
    "6": 1492849091,
    "7": 1491850005,
    "8": 1486520272,
    "9": 1490253605,
    "10": 1492000548
}
```

I need to serialize this JSON to pojo. How to build my java pojo class for this example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON Object keys will be the Java property names.

If you don't know what they'll be ahead of time, which is what it seems like here, you can deserialize directly to type `java.util.Map`, where the keys on your `Map` instance would match those of the JSON Object keys.

Once you have your `Map` you could iterate over the entries or keys to do something with each value.

If you have a Jackson `ObjectMapper` instance available, you could do something like

```
Map<String, Integer> values = (Map<String, Integer>) myObjectMapper.readValue(jsonString, java.util.Map.class);
```